# What are pros and cons of using && or || versus if/elif/else?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

In bash, I can make a test condition utilize && and/or || rather than an if/elif/else block.

When applicable, I use tend to use && and/or || rather than building out an if block. Are there any real-world advantages to one construct over the other?

Consider the following examples:

1)

```
[[ -f /shared_disk/backups/daily.tar.bz2 ]] && echo "the coast is clear" || echo "run the dump"
```

2)

```
if [[ -f /shared_disk/backups/daily.tar.bz2 ]]; then
    echo "the coast is clear"
else
    echo "run the dump"
fi
```

Comment: Discussed tangentially in [How to conditionally do something if a command succeeds or fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22726/23408);  see also [Why doesn’t this fairly simple “if” work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252011/23408)

Comment: Also related: [When is 'if' not necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158676/23408)

Answer (score 5):

The two forms you present are not exactly equal.

In the form: `A && B || C`, `C` will be executed if either `A` or `B` evaluate as false.

For example:

```
$ true && true || echo C
$ true && false || echo C
C
$
```

This gives one real-world advantage of the `if-then-else` form over the `A && B || C` form and that is clarity. It is clearer what the `if-then-else` form is doing, but you need to understand the rules of evaluation to understand what the `A && B || C` form is doing.

However it can often be beneficial to use `A && B` or `A || B`. That is clearer and can be useful when simple commands are being run. Sometimes one line instead of three is clearer, particularly when you're trying to take in a large amount of code.

Comment: IMO the most confusing thing about using `&& ||` instead of `if then else` is that it can run both the then-like command *and* the else-like command (if the first command succeeds and the second fails). You don't really expect a `echo` command to fail, but it can happen, and it'll be really really confusing if it ever does. A proper `if then else` statement runs either the `then` command(s) or the `else` commands, *never* both.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Why don’t you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Scott: I consider camh's answer entirely correct as it is, I'm just pointing out a particularly troubling consequence.